How to compare a subset of the Column of a table with the column of another table in SQL?
Table 1:
Name    Address   Height    Weight
X.        y         z.        p
G.        H.        I         J
Q         W.        E.        R

Table 2:
Name    Income     Tax    
X.        y         z
A         B         C

Trying compare the rows between the two tables and get the names that appear only in table 1 and not in table 2 as well? However, I am only trying to compare only certain rows from table_1, for example - the rows which contain Height= I and E do not need to be on the count.
Here is what I have so far but I am getting a syntax error:
SELECT count(DISTINCT "Name") FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.Height NOT LIKE ANY CONCAT('%', {'I', 'E'} '%')

WHERE NOT EXISTS (

    SELECT DISTINCT UPPER("Name") FROM table_2 WHERE table_2."Income" = 'y' AND UPPER(table_2."Name") LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(table_1."Name"), '%')

)

syntax error at or near "WHERE"

The result of the query should be 1 as there is a count() but without count it should look like
Name    Address   Height    Weight
X.        y         z.        p


WHERE WHERE, that can't work. Replace the second WHERE by an AND

Please show what the result of the query should look like.

You can't write whatever you want to write and expect the system to understand what you want.  There are syntax to follow.

Can you left join table 2 to table 1 and filter for where name in table 2 is null?
ie:
SELECT table1.*
FROM 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE Height NOT LIKE '%E%' 
     and Height NOT LIKE '%I%') table1
LEFT JOIN table2
  ON table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table2.name is null


Sorry,for me it is not very clear what you want to achieve, but based on this " get the names that appear only in table 1 and not in table 2 as well? However, I am only trying to compare only certain rows from table_1, for example - the rows which contain Height= I and E do not need to be on the count"
WITH TABLE_1(NAME,ADDRESS,HEIGHT,WEIGHT) AS
(
  SELECT 'X','Y','Z','P' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'G','H','I','J' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'Q','W','E','R'
),
TABLE_2(NAME,INCOME,TAX) AS
(
  SELECT 'X','Y','Z' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'A','B','C'
)
SELECT COUNT(*)AS CNTT FROM
(
   SELECT T1.NAME
   FROM TABLE_1 AS T1
   WHERE T1.HEIGHT NOT IN('E','I')
     EXCEPT 
   SELECT T2.NAME
  FROM TABLE_2 AS T2
)AS X


From the comment by Frank Heikens, WHERE WHERE, that can't work. Replace the second WHERE by an AND. That worked.

Here's what I cam up with.  You do know that this will have no results...
create table Table_1
(Name       varchar(2)
,Address    varchar(2)
,Height     varchar(2)
,Weight     varchar(2)); commit;
--=================================================================================
insert into Table_1 (Name, Address, Height, Weight) values ('X.', 'y', 'z.', 'p'); commit;
insert into Table_1 (Name, Address, Height, Weight) values ('G.', 'H.', 'I', 'J'); commit;
insert into Table_1 (Name, Address, Height, Weight) values ('Q', 'W.', 'E.', 'R'); commit;
-- select * from Table_1
--=================================================================================
--=================================================================================
create table Table_2
(Name       varchar(2)
,Income     varchar(2)
,Tax        varchar(2)); commit;
--=================================================================================
insert into Table_2 (Name, Income, Tax) values ('X.', 'y', 'z'); commit;
insert into Table_2 (Name, Income, Tax) values ('A', 'B', 'C'); commit;
-- select * from Table_2
--=================================================================================
--=================================================================================
select distinct name from Table_1 t1 where t1.height not in ('I','E.') and t1.Name not in (select distinct Name from Table_2);
